# AngularJS: how to avoid this behavior when data.length is on zero?

Tags: angularjs

I have an alert which shows up to the user when an array named `lineItemsF.length` is on zero. I am working on a single page app, so once the user logs in that array is going to be on zero, after a couple seconds the data will load so that array will have some items, so, the alert will disappear.

That alert is actually something that I am using in a filter, in a search box in this case, when the user types something in that search box and filter returns nothing, then the alert comes up.

I made a video for you to understand whats happening, just look at the red banner at the top of the screen which automatically remove once the data load. That's not what I want, all I want is to see that alert once the user types something incorrectly in the search box.

I though that using `$pristine` or `$dirty` will work, but I do not know if I used those attrs incorrectly.

[here is the video my friends](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMUkJi_X3MQ&feature=youtu.be)

```
 <!--this is the alert-->
<div  class="alert"
      ng-show="!lineItemsF.length">Did not match any search criteria
</div>
<!--this is the alert-->

    <div ng-repeat="lineItem in lineItemsF = (lineItems | filter:search)">

      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">{{:: lineLeague[0].leagueName}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table table-bordered tables">
            <thead class="tableHeader">
            <tr>
              ...
            </tr>
            </thead>
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put this in your alert conditions

```
<div  class="alert"
      ng-show="searchCriteria.length > 0 && !lineItemsF.length">Did not match any search criteria
</div>
```

searchCriteria is the value inside the search input, so it will be displayed only if the criteria is not null (or length > 0).

Comment: I did it this way and works ```ng-show="lineItemsF.length==0"``` is there any bad point or I should use your way ?

Comment: This is the "cheapest" way to make this work (I would just go with this approach). A more robust way would be to set `$scope.isLoading` and hide the results section while the data is loading

Comment: @NewDev are you talking about the way I did it ```ng-show="lineItemsF.length==0"``` ?

Comment: @TheUnnamed, I meant the way Mathieu answered it. Your way would not (did not) work, right? It shows the alert while items are loading. You need to augment it with something else, like `searchCriteria.length > 0`

Comment: @TheUnnamed, That's probably because your `$scope.lineItems === undefined`. If it was `$scope.lineItems = []` prior to loading, then it would not work. Just my guess, since you don't show your code.

Comment: this how I have it ```$scope.lineItems = {};``` @NewDev

Comment: Mathieu, where is ```searchCriteria``` coming from ? can you explain that I little bit ? or you @NewDev please

Comment: Mathieu meant by `searchCriteria` that it is the scope variable for the search query. I think, you refer to it as just `search`, judging by `| filter: search` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-cloak` in your div
   or
  `ng-show="lineItemsF.length!=0"`